# Create wmv-file from code?

Tags: vb.net, wmv

I have a project where the requirements is that a end user will select a template, enter some information and then my program should create a wmv movie file that has the information entered encoded in the movie.

So from my perspective I would like to have a framework that allows me to add graphics and text to a movie. Something like this:

```
movie.addframes(framecount, templateimage)  
movie.frame(x).drawtext(x,y,text,font,size,color)   
movie.frame(x).drawRectangle(rect,color,bordersize)  
movie.frame(x).drawImage(rect,borderstyle,bordersize, image,sizemode)
movie.save(filename,filetype)
```

Does this exists?

I have searched and only found information about ffmpeg that doesn't seem to do what I want.
I don't need it to be real-time encoding.
I don't care if the framework/library is expensive.

If there are information of how to do this with for example DirectX or DirectShow and pointing to real working vb.net examples, then ill be happy too. ;)  (Believe me, I have tried to search and haven't found anything.)

I have not found any good information about how to use Windows Media Encoder for this, but It seems like Windows Media Encoder is the way to go if doing it myself..

Comment: I have the same question. Incredible that you got no answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use DirectShow, check **Samples\Capture\CapWMV** [here](http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?group_id=136334&release_id=412758)

Comment: I cant se any posibilitys to change the example from streaming "webcam to movie" to do what I want. But I'll check out all examples and see if some other examples there can help me. Thanks anyway.